# PHP Email Sender: Full name telling "unknown sender"

Tags: php, email, sendmail, html-email

```
if(empty($_POST)=== false){
    //send email

    $fullname = $_REQUEST['fullname'];
    $names = $_REQUEST["fullname"];
    $phonenumber = $_REQUEST['phonenumber'];
    $mobilenumber = $_REQUEST['mobilenumber'];
    $postcode = $_REQUEST['postcode'];
    $level = $_REQUEST['level'];
    $creditors = $_REQUEST['creditors'] ;
    $status = $_REQUEST['status'] ;
    $monthly = $_REQUEST['monthly'] ;
    $partner = $_REQUEST['partner'] ;
    $subject="The Debt Advice Service";
    $message = "Full Name: ".$fullname. " \n\n";
    $message .="Phone Number: ". $phonenumber."\n\n";
    $message .="Mobile Number: ".$mobilenumber."\n\n";
    $message .="Postcode: ".$postcode."\n\n";
    $message .="Level Of Debt: ".$level."\n\n";
    $message .="How many debts / creditors: ".$creditors."\n\n";
    $message .="Employment Status: ".$status."\n\n"; 
    $message .="Monthly Income (&pound;): ".$monthly."\n\n"; 
    $message .="Partner's Income(&pound;): ".$partner."\n\n"; 
    $headers = 'From: '.$names."\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    //$name = $_REQUEST['fullname']; 
    //$headers = "From: $name";

     mail("mymail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
     mail("mymail.com", $subject, $message,  $headers);
}
```

The output:

[image]

I got an issue at `$header` because if I input one-word name, the name is valid but if I put a full name, the sender will tell "unknown sender" please help me with my problem.

Comment: Try changing your form and your code to `$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];` and `$lastname = $_REQUEST["lastname"];` then change `$message = "Full Name: ".$fullname. " \n\n";` to `$message = "Full Name: " .$firstname $lastname. "\n\n";`

Comment: Try changing this `$headers = 'From: '.$names."\r\n".` to `$headers = 'From: '.$fullname."\r\n".` see what that gives you for now, till we figure out exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: Working with a `COPY` of your code, try changing all `$_REQUEST` instances to `$_POST`.

Comment: still the same I chnange    $names = $_REQUEST["fullname"]; into  $names = $_POST["fullname"];  but still desame

Comment: From declaration in the header is expecting an email address, so names wont work the spaces will probably break it and not output an error, but no email address will accept it properly.

Comment: If your form's email field is called `email`, try changing `$headers = 'From: '.$names."\r\n".` to `$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".` see what that gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fill up all the contents so that the form has data to parse for all fields. After that, you can use JQuery or third party plugins (parsley.js) for Data Validations for the required to be filled and formatted. By that way your form works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the answer for this question that you must fill up all the contents in order to view the name of the sender